# Dockerfile installs Meteor globally, not locally

Tags: linux, bash, meteor, docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile installs Meteor on the image. Only problem is when I log in to my non root user and run `meteor` it then begins to download and install it locally. So it recognises `meteor` as a command but it is not available immediately to run my app-code. How can I make it available to my non root user.

[image]

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

# update the system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl \
    apt-utils \
    locales \
    nano \
    python

RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh

# Set the locale
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8 

# create a user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash dev
ENV HOME=/home
WORKDIR $HOME/dev

RUN chmod -R 777 ~
RUN chown -R dev: /home/dev
USER dev
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Done (it's a fair point)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create the user and switch the `WORK_DIR` before installing meteor.

Also you should consider using this https://github.com/jshimko/meteor-launchpad

Answer (score 0):

You have to run meteor install after you change the user otherwise you are running the meteor install with root user.

```
RUN chmod -R 777 ~
RUN chown -R dev: /home/dev
USER dev

RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```